# extract multiple value from dictionary in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have JSON data coming from the API link.

```yaml
---
- hosts: xxxx
  tasks:
   - name: check subs
     uri:
      url: https://xxxxx/api/v2/hosts
      user: xxxx
      password: xxxx
      method: GET
      force_basic_auth: yes
      return_content: yes
      status_code: [200]
      body_format: json
     register: data
     ignore_errors: true

   - debug:
      var: data.json['results'][0].certname
     ignore_errors: true
```

with this, I get only the first item

```yaml
ok: [xxxxx] => {
    "data.json['results'][0].certname": "xxxxxx"
```

How can I get all the values of the certname? I have like 50 values for the key certname. How can I do this in Ansible?

```yaml
            "certname": “x”xxx,
            "comment": null,
            "compute_profile_id": null,
            "compute_profile_name": null,
            "compute_resource_id": null,
            "compute_resource_name": null,
            "content_facet_attributes": {
                "applicable_module_stream_count": 0,
                "applicable_package_count": 28,
                "content_source": null,
                "content_source_id": null,
                "content_source_name": null,
                "content_view": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": “xxxx”
                },
                "content_view_id": 1,
                "content_view_name": “xxxx”,
                "errata_counts": {
                    "bugfix": 9,
                    "enhancement": 4,
                    "security": 4,
                    "total": 17
                },
                "id": xxx,
                "kickstart_repository": null,
                "kickstart_repository_id": null,
                "kickstart_repository_name": null,
                "lifecycle_environment": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Library"
                },
                "lifecycle_environment_id": 1,
                "lifecycle_environment_name": "Library",
                "upgradable_module_stream_count": 0,
                "upgradable_package_count": 28,
                "uuid": “xxxxx”
            },
            "created_at": “x”xxxx,
            "disk": null,
            "domain_id": null,
            "domain_name": null,
            "enabled": true,
            "environment_id": null,
            "environment_name": null,
            "errata_status": 3,
            "errata_status_label": “xxx,
            "global_status": 2,
            "global_status_label": "Error",
            "hostgroup_id": null,
            "hostgroup_name": null,
            "hostgroup_title": null,
            "id": 35,
            "image_file": "",
            "image_id": null,
            "image_name": null,
            "installed_at": null,
            "ip": "1x”xxxx,
            "ip6": null,
            "last_compile": "2021-06-17 08:45:41 UTC",
            "last_report": null,
            "location_id": 2,
            "location_name": “xx”x,
            "mac": “xxxx”,
            "managed": false,
            "medium_id": null,
            "medium_name": null,
            "model_id": 1,
            "model_name": “xx”x,
            "name": “xxx”x,
            "openscap_proxy": null,
            "openscap_proxy_id": null,
            "openscap_proxy_name": null,
            "operatingsystem_id": 3,
            "operatingsystem_name": "RedHat xx”,
            "organization_id": x,
            "organization_name": “xxx”x,
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "Anonymous Admin",
            "owner_type": "User",
            "provision_method": "build",
            "ptable_id": null,
            "ptable_name": null,
            "puppet_ca_proxy": null,
            "puppet_ca_proxy_id": null,
            "puppet_ca_proxy_name": null,
            "puppet_proxy": null,
            "puppet_proxy_id": null,
            "puppet_proxy_name": null,
            "puppet_status": 0,
            "purpose_addons_status": 3,
            "purpose_addons_status_label": "Not Specified",
            "purpose_role_status": 3,
            "purpose_role_status_label": "Not Specified",
            "purpose_sla_status": 3,
            "purpose_sla_status_label": "Not Specified",
            "purpose_status": 3,
            "purpose_status_label": "Not Specified",
            "purpose_usage_status": 3,
            "purpose_usage_status_label": "Not Specified",
            "pxe_loader": null,
            "realm_id": null,
            "realm_name": null,
            "sp_ip": null,
            "sp_mac": null,
            "sp_name": null,
            "sp_subnet_id": null,
            "subnet6_id": null,
            "subnet6_name": null,
            "subnet_id": null,
            "subnet_name": null,
            "subscription_facet_attributes": {
                "autoheal": true,
                "hypervisor": false,
                "id": xx,
                "last_checkin": "2021-07-08 23:22:31 UTC",
                "purpose_addons": [],
                "purpose_role": "",
                "purpose_usage": "",
                "registered_at": "2021-06-12 16:42:05 UTC",
                "registered_through": “xxxx”,
                "release_version": null,
                "service_level": "",
                "user": null,
                "uuid": “xxxxx”
            },
            "subscription_global_status": 0,
            "subscription_status": 0,
            "subscription_status_label": “Unentitled”,
            "updated_at": "2021-06-20 00:45:49 UTC",
            "uptime_seconds": 1882980,
            "use_image": null,
            "uuid": null
        },
```

```yaml
   - debug:
      msg: "{{ data.json.results|map(attribute='certname')|list }}"
     #when: "{{ data.json['results']|map(attribute='subscription_status_label')|list }}" == "Unentitled"
     when: "{{ data.json['results']|selectattr('subscription_status_label', 'search' , 'Unentitled') }}"
     ignore_errors: true
```

Comment: Amit, You may get answer to this question in current state. However it would be lot easier for the folks who plan to answer if you could provide sample `dictionary`. Eg: Content of `data` register. OR at least a sample content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```yaml
   - debug:
      msg: "{{ data.json.results|map(attribute='certname')|list }}"
```

---

Q: *"**Get only those 'certname' whose 'subscription_status' is unentitled.**"*

A: Given the simplified data below

```yaml
    data:
      json:
        results:
          - certname: AAA
            comment: Company A
            subscription_status_label: Unentitled
          - certname: BBB
            comment: Company B
            subscription_status_label: Entitled
          - certname: CCC
            comment: Company C
            subscription_status_label: Unentitled
```

the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ data.json.results|
                 selectattr('subscription_status_label', 'eq' , 'Unentitled')|
                 map(attribute='certname')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - AAA
  - CCC
```

Comment: But I want to add condition on this. i.e. only those certname whose subscription_status is unentitled.

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre], or open a new question.

Comment: I have edited the question with the data and code.

Comment: @Amit, make it [mre]. See the answer as an example of what's minimal.